# Dynamic Block not showing

Tags: 7, blocks

My block is not showing in the blocks menu for some reason and im sure everything is correct on it, am I missing something on it?

.info file

```
; $Id: loans_zillow.info,v 1.0.0.0 2011/02/09 10:11:15 Jeremy Exp $
name = "Custom Zllow Module"
version = "1.0 Beta"
description = "A custom module from zillow's api"
core = "7.x"
package = "Custom Modules"
```

.module file

```
   function zillow_block_info(){
        $blocks['zillow_block'] = array(
            'info' => t('Zillow Block'),
        );
        return $blocks;
    }

    function zillow_block_view($delta = ''){
        $block = array();
        switch ($delta){
            case 'zillow_block';
            $block['subject'] = t('Zillow Block');
            $block['content'] = zillow_content();
            break;
        }
        return $block;
    }

    function zillow_content(){
        return'
            <div>this is a test</div>
        ';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me so I'd check the following:

- Make sure the module's installed and enabled.
- Make sure the module is definitely named `zillow` (the module file should be called `zillow.module`, info file `zillow.info`, etc).
- Make sure you've cleared Drupal's caches.

I realise these might be obvious solutions but as I say the code works for me so I can only guess your hooks are not being called for one of the reasons above.

Comment: There was a l instead of a i in zillow on my file name thats what messed it up. Thanks though